# IOS | Loading in RSS feed which contains HTML tags

Tags: html, ios, rss, blogs

I'm creating my first IOS app where i'm loading in an [RSS feed from my blog](http://www.wesleysmits.com/rss/).

As you can see the RSS feed contains several

and  tags. When loading the description part of the xml in my app the html tags are shown there. Of course i just want to show the text marked up beautifully like it is on the website.

The first thing i did was run a function to remove all the tags. Didn't give me a pretty result though. The biggest problem however is that i have code examples in most of my blog posts. These code bits should not be filtered out of course..

Anyone know how i can mark up my text in a good way without losing the code from the examples?

Comment: Why not use UIWebView?

Comment: I want the app to have a native style. In the future more RSS feeds will be added to the list.

Comment: Then I would not use rss but I would write an api on your server to deliver a JSON encoded article and then convert it to an NSObject. That way you can make it look however you want.

Comment: Hey @Mikael that would be better for my own website(s) indeed. But in the future i would like to include feeds from blogs that i do not own myself. Therefor i wanted to go with the RSS feed. Rss feeds are way more common for blogs to have than an API of course.